# Date format conversion results wrong date

Tags: php, date, type-conversion

I tried converting

```
12-18-1997
```

to

```
18-12-1997
```

with this code

```
$new_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('12-18-1997'));
```

but it results in `18-12-1969`

If I have to convert full date alongwith time then its converting fine but in the date I posted in question there is no time.

Comment: Please dont mark it duplicate. If I have to convert full date alongwith time then its converting fine but in the date I posted in question there is no time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) instead of `strtotime()`:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'm-d-Y', '12-18-1997');
echo $date->format( 'd-m-Y');
```

You can see from [this demo](http://3v4l.org/3Pjqu) that it prints:

```
18-12-1997
```

Comment: I am getting this error. Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat()

Comment: @ImranTariq - Then PHP is older than version 5.3, and it's time to upgrade.

Comment: I checked Program Versions from cpanel. There PHP version is: 5.3.24

Answer (score 0):

strtotime is good, but it's not psychic or omniscient. you're feeding it a time string it's not able to parse properly:

```
php > var_dump(strtotime('12-18-1997'));
bool(false)
```

Since you simply assumed it's succeeding, you feed that `false` back to `date()`, where it's type-cast to an integer 0. However, your result is impossible, since int 0 as a date is Jan 1/1970. With timezone conversions, it'd be `31-12-1969` for you, **NOT** `18-12`.

If you can't feed strtotime a format it understands, then use date_create_from_format and TELL it what what the format is:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', '12-18-1997');
$text = date('d-m-Y', $date);
```

Comment: error comes.  Call to undefined function date_create_from_format()

Comment: Then your PHP version is too old. Definitely time to upgrade.

Comment: I checked Program Versions from cpanel. There PHP version is:
5.3.24

Comment: then something is very weird in your php install, because datetime was added in 5.3.0